# Return from nested blocks, scope issue

Tags: go, scope

## Basic concept

I'm learning Go and I can't understand how to return data from an inner block of a function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    if isTrue("asasa") {
        fmt.Println("isTrue is true")
    }
}

func isTrue(s string) bool {
    if s == "asasa" {
        fmt.Println("it matches")
        return true
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/x6l29CNdg-o

How should I return a condition met inside a nested (**even multiple time nested**) block?

## Real case scenario

```
func isUnique(h, c, L float64) bool {

    for i, color := range usuedColors {
        if color[0] == h && color[1] == c && color[2] == L {
            fmt.Println("This color already exist!")
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

I receive a triple of values `h, c, L` and I want to check if it is unique against a 2D slice where I've previously stored other triples.
I cycle through all the triple and if a match exist I want `isUnique` to return as false, else true.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, just `return`.

Comment: If I add a simple return before the function closing it is a compile error as it wants a bool and not () (yielded by a `return`

Comment: So return a bool then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for value returned from the function, assign it to variable and use it in main when checking for the condition as below:
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    if ok := isTrue("asasa"); ok {
        fmt.Println("isTrue is true")
    }
}

func isTrue(s string) bool {
    boolean := false
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        if s == "asasa" {
            fmt.Println("it matches")
            boolean = true
        }
    }
    return boolean
}
```

In Golang Effective Go for [If control statement](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if) it is described:

> Since if and switch accept an initialization statement, it's common to
>   see one used to set up a local variable.

```
if err := file.Chmod(0664); err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
    return err
}
```

> In the Go libraries, you'll find that when an if statement doesn't
>   flow into the next statement—that is, the body ends in break,
>   continue, goto, or return—the unnecessary else is omitted.

```
f, err := os.Open(name)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
codeUsing(f)
```

It is also used in maps to check if value exists or not on basis of keys. Check this link for [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps) on maps to know more about `comma ok` syntax.

Working code updated on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jialeeotr7v)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm sorry and I recognize this is a silly question but on Effective Go and A tour of Go these "tricks" aren't explained at all.
Do you have by chance lower level go documentation to suggest?

Comment: The solution and the comma ok method is valid only for 1 level nested blocks however, enclosing the if in a for breaks again the whole thing. https://play.golang.org/p/h8ViAT7s7po

I'd like to understand how to return from an unlimited or at least few multiple nested blocks.

I'm sorry had to un-accept the asnwer.

Comment: @Maxiride ok check my edited answer for if statements. Please edit your post for more information so that I will try to understand what exactly you want from code side

Comment: @Maxiride you can create a variable with `false` as default value and then change it where your condition satisfies that will help you to write return statement only once

Comment: Please comment if you are downvoting don't just downvote without any reason

Comment: modified the question with a real case scenario

Edit: I can't downvote apparently as I'm under 125 rep.

Comment: @Maxiride: This answer contains some bad advice.

Comment: @Maxiride check my answer for nested returns

Comment: @Himanshu accepted it! I get it now, but is so much more verbose than I could ever thought to add a "placeholder" variable `boolean := false` to make it visible in the outer scope.

Comment: @Maxiride returning a value is proper way to work in your condition. if your function has a return

Comment: @Himanshu ok I'll surely keep this "workflow" in mind. 

thanks for your patience and time, really appreciated 

Am I right in assuming that this kind of checking has a smarter way to be done without "placeholder" variables?

Comment: @Maxiride your welcome, well this is not go kind of problem but this is how you structure your code. I am sure there can be other patterns. But go also follows this pattern. Also it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your compile error: `: missing return at end of function`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    if isTrue("asasa") {
        fmt.Println("isTrue is true")
    }
}

func isTrue(s string) bool {
    if s == "asasa" {
        fmt.Println("it matches")
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/AYj7tcXd49k

Output:

```
Hello, playground
it matches
isTrue is true
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Return statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)
>
> A "return" statement in a function F terminates the execution of F.

---

For the real case that you just added:

```
func isUnique(h, c, L float64) bool {
    for i, color := range usedColors {
        if color[0] == h && color[1] == c && color[2] == L {
            fmt.Println("This color already exist!")
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer how to return from multiple nested blocks however. I shouldn't have made that simple example as it is biasing the answers.

Comment: @Maxiride: I have added your new example to my answer.

Comment: So in this case the inner return in the if acts as a break too?

Comment: @Maxiride: Yes. The `return` statement acts as a function level break. It exits the  function irrespective of how deeply it is nested. See the reference to `return` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is a general logic problem rather than a golang problem or returning from a block. The problem with your code:

```
func isUnique(h, c, L float64) bool {
    for i, color := range usuedColors {
        if color[0] == h && color[1] == c && color[2] == L {
            fmt.Println("This color already exist!")
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Is that it only checks the very first color, not all of them. What you *really* want is to first check if any of them match

```
    for i, color := range usuedColors {
        if color[0] == h && color[1] == c && color[2] == L {
            fmt.Println("This color already exist!")
            return false
        }
    }
```

And *only if* none of them matched, return true.

```
func isUnique(h, c, L float64) bool {
    for i, color := range usuedColors {
        if color[0] == h && color[1] == c && color[2] == L {
            fmt.Println("This color already exist!")
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```